# jQuery - false if AJAX result is xyz not recognised

Tags: javascript, jquery, smart-wizard

I am displaying a wizard form and at some stage have to check whether the entered `property_code` input value matches any record in the database. This is done via jQuery and AJAX call, which responds with either `Valid` or `Invalid`, based on which I may want to stop the user from being able to move to the next page of the wizard.

Now, this feature is supported by the `smartwizard()` plugin and should work, but there seems to be a jQuery issue when validating the AJAX response. I see the response is `Invalid`, yet the user can still move on to the next slide, suggesting there is a problem when returning `true` or `false`.

```
// Initialize the leaveStep event
$("#smartwizard").on("leaveStep", function(e, anchorObject, stepIndex, nextStepIndex, stepDirection) {
    // console
    console.log('LeaveStep - CurrentStepIndex: ' + stepIndex);

    // Property Info - checks if property exists before leaving step 1
    if (stepIndex == 1) {

        //check if property code already exists in system
        var property_code = $("#property_code").val();
        console.log('Checking if property code "' + property_code + '" already exists in DB');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../../controllers/hom_check_property_code.php',
            data: 'action=check_property_code&property_code=' + property_code,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log('Property check response: ' + response);

                if (response == 'Invalid') {
                    console.log('Property code check failed');
                    return false;
                } else {
                    console.log('Property code check passed');
                    return true;
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log('Ajax POST request failed.');
                console.error(xhr);
            }
        });
    }

    // navigate to next step
    console.log('Navigating from stepIndex ' + stepIndex + ' to ' + nextStepIndex + ', moving in stepDirection ' + stepDirection);
    return true;
});
```

I am not good with jquery / JS, hence would appreciate if someone could explain me where the problem is? I understand that returning `false` should stop the remainder of the script from that point onward, so not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: returning a value from the `success` callback is meaningless, those returns do nothing - also the code after `// navigate to next step` is executed before the `$.ajax`  even starts, let alone completes - the first `a` in `ajax` means **asynchronous** if that helps

Comment: Your `if (response == 'Invalid') { return false` only returns to the $.ajax success call - it doesn't "return" to your leaveStep event, which will have already returned sometime earlier.

Comment: Put another way, the `return` returns to the nearest `function` (or `()=>`) not to the/an outer function.

Comment: so looking at the suggested answer, the "right" way of doing things would be to call a function when the ajax call is `.done` that in turn triggers what I want the next step to be?

Comment: @Armitage2k Since the ajax call is asynchronous, you need to cancel the `leaveStep` event by returning false and call `$("#smartwizard")smartWizard("next")` on ajax success call back. Please check the thread here for example https://github.com/techlab/jquery-smartwizard/issues/20#issuecomment-286723131